# Markov chain and time to absorption problem

Tags: probability, statistics

[image]

My attempt to solve the problem:

[image]

However, the right solution is 6 steps.
I appreciate your help.

Comment: I don't understand your transition matrix. The first line should give you the probability, starting from A, to go to B and C, and thus should be (0, 1/2, 1.2). 
Edit : okay I think I understand what you wanted to do, by bringing the whole set $(B,C)$ as one point. But even in this case your last line in the second transition matrix should be (1/2,1/2) rather than (1/2,0) (which does not even sum to 1).

Comment: And by the way, if you consider only two states instead of one, your mean absorption time will not be right. For instance it allows you to come back to A after 2 steps and to consider it as a full turn, which it is not.